# Microsoft Word Find (letter paragraph letter) and Replace paragraph with space but leave letters

Tags: microsoft-word, search, find-and-replace, microsoft-word-2016

In Microsoft Word I want to Find (letter paragraph letter) (^$^p^$) and Replace the paragraph with a space but not change the letters.

**Example:**

Hello`^p`World

**Output:**

Hello World

**Current Output:**

Hellorld

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to do this using the 'wild-cards' option in the find/replace box. But for reasons known only to Microsoft you can't use ^p when the wildcard option is selected. So we have to use a two stage proces:

**(1) Use Find/Replace without Wildcards to flag up paragraph marks. **

```
Make sure 'wildcards' is de-selected
Find ^p and replace with ¬^p¬
```

The '¬' character can be any character (or sequence) that does not occur naturally in your document. It is just a temporary marker.

** (2) Replace paragraph marker between words using wildcards

```
Make sure that the Wildcards option is selected
Find: (<[a-z,A-Z]@>)¬?¬(<[a-z,A-Z]@>)
Replace: \1 \2
```

<[a-z,A-Z]@> finds words 
Putting () around them records them for use in the Replace phase, accessed by referencing \1, \2, etc

That should cover it - hope it makes some kind of sense to you.

Comment: Unbelievable answer!!!!!